# Can someone explain how this code converts volume to decibels using the Accelerate Framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, accelerate-framework, ezaudio

I'm building an iOS app using EZAudio. It's delegate returns back a `float**` buffer, which contains float values indicating the volume detected. This delegate is called constantly and it's work is done a different thread.

> **What I am trying to do is to take the float value from EZAudio and convert it into decibels.**

---

### EZAudioDelegate

Here's my simplified [EZAudio Delegate for getting Microphone Data](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio#getting-microphone-data):

```
- (void)microphone:(EZMicrophone *)microphone hasAudioReceived:(float **)buffer withBufferSize:(UInt32)bufferSize withNumberOfChannels:(UInt32)numberOfChannels {
    /*
     *  Returns a float array called buffer that contains the stereo signal data
     *  buffer[0] is the left audio channel
     *  buffer[1] is the right audio channel
     */

    // Using a separate audio thread to not block the main UI thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        float decibels = [self getDecibelsFromVolume:buffer withBufferSize:bufferSize];

        NSLog(@"Decibels: %f", decibels);

    });

}
```

---

### The Problem

> **The problem is that after implementing solutions from the links below, I do not understand how it works. If someone could explain how it converts volume to decibels I would be very grateful**

- [How to convert audio input to DB? #85](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio/issues/85)
- [How to change the buffer size to increase FFT window? #50](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio/issues/50)
- [Changing Buffer Size #84](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio/issues/84)

---

### The Code

The solution uses the following methods from the [Accelerate Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009465) to convert the volume into decibels:

- [vDSP_vsq](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_vsq)
- [vDSP_meanv](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_meanv)
- [vDSP_vdbcon](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_vdbcon)

Below is the method `getDecibelsFromVolume` that is called from the EZAudio Delegate. It is passed the `float** buffer` and `bufferSize` from the delegate.

```
- (float)getDecibelsFromVolume:(float**)buffer withBufferSize:(UInt32)bufferSize {

    // Decibel Calculation.

    float one = 1.0;
    float meanVal = 0.0;
    float tiny = 0.1;
    float lastdbValue = 0.0;

    vDSP_vsq(buffer[0], 1, buffer[0], 1, bufferSize);

    vDSP_meanv(buffer[0], 1, &meanVal, bufferSize);

    vDSP_vdbcon(&meanVal, 1, &one, &meanVal, 1, 1, 0);


    // Exponential moving average to dB level to only get continous sounds.

    float currentdb = 1.0 - (fabs(meanVal) / 100);

    if (lastdbValue == INFINITY || lastdbValue == -INFINITY || isnan(lastdbValue)) {
        lastdbValue = 0.0;
    }

    float dbValue = ((1.0 - tiny) * lastdbValue) + tiny * currentdb;

    lastdbValue = dbValue;

    return dbValue;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at Accelerate/vDSP.h for what the vDSP functions do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll explain how one would compute a dB value for a signal using code and then show how that relates to the vDSP example.

#### First, compute the RMS sum of a chunk of data

```
double sumSquared = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < numSamples ; i++)
{
   sumSquared += samples[i]*samples[i];
}
double rms = sumSquared/numSamples;
```

For more information on [RMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square)

#### Next convert the RMS value to dB

```
double dBvalue = 20*log10(rms);
```

#### How this relates to the example code

```
vDSP_vsq(buffer[0], 1, buffer[0], 1, bufferSize);
```

This line loops over the buffer and computes squares all of the elements in the buffer. If buffer contained the values `[1,2,3,4]` before the call then after the call it would contain the values `[1,4,9,16]`

```
vDSP_meanv(buffer[0], 1, &meanVal, bufferSize);
```

This line loops over the buffer, summing the values in the buffer and then returning the sum divided by the number of elements. So for the input buffer `[1,4,9,16]` in computes the sum `30`, divides by `4` and returns the result `7.5`.

```
vDSP_vdbcon(&meanVal, 1, &one, &meanVal, 1, 1, 0);
```

This line converts the `meanVal` to decibels. There is really no point in calling a vectorized function here since it is only operating on a single element. What it is doing however is plugging the parameters into the following formula:

```
meanVal = n*log10(meanVal/one)
```

where `n` is either `10` or `20` depending on the last parameter. In this case it is `10`. `10` is used for power measurements and `20` is used for amplitudes. I think `20` would make more sense for you to use.

The last little bit of code looks to be doing some simple smoothing of the result to make the meter a little less bouncy.

Comment: Thanks very much @jacket! 

Could you please explain what you mean by:

`"There is really no point in calling a vectorized function here since it is only operating on a single element."`

Are you are referring to `vDSP_vdbcon` when you say `vectorized function`?

What would the change be?

Comment: What I mean is that the `vDSP_vdbcon` is optimized to convert an array of values to dB yet your code is only calling it with the single float `meanVal`. It's not really pointless, it's just not going to have any performance benefit from writing coding it like `meanVal = 20*log10(meanVal);`

Comment: Oh god.. Apple really likes to complicate things. Thanks a lot for the explanation.